# Javascript div doesn't work

Tags: javascript

```
var udiv = document.createElement('div');
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.style.width = "100px";
div.style.height = "100px";
div.style.background = "red";
div.style.color = "white";
div.innerHTML = "Hello";
div.appendChild(udiv);
```

I've been trying to get this to work, but when I open the page there's nothing there. I know the Javascript file works because everything else shows up, but the div doesn't. There's no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But both are *new* elements, Append those elements to an already existing element or to the *`body`*,

```
.
.
.
div.appendChild(udiv);
document.body.appendChild(div)
```

Comment: I've tired that, all it does is cause this error: main.js:182 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null

Comment: @BubbieBell where you are placing your script? Place it under the closing tag of body/or use [domcontentloaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_%28event%29?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_event_reference%2FDOMContentLoaded) event.

Comment: @BubbieBell Glad to help! :) Try to press the tick mark present inside anyone of the answers here which helped you to solve your problem. And this is not a compulsion. :)

Answer (score 1):

You've appended `udiv` to `div`, but you've never appended `div` to the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't append the `div` object to the DOM

`document.body.appendChild(div);`